# Accessing business object?

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to implement similar structure as 'Gang of Four' design pattern. But i am stuck at on point. Below is the issue.

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Category=new Category();
    }

    public Product(int productId, string productName, string weight, double unitPrice, int unitsInStock)
        : this()
    {
        ProductId = productId;
        ProductName = productName;
        Weight = weight;
        UnitPrice = unitPrice;
        UnitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string Weight { get; set; }

    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }


}

public class Category :
{

    public Category()
    {

    }
    public Category(int categoryId, string name, string description)
        : this()
    {
        CategoryId = categoryId;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
```

To get the List of product via below.

```
public List<Product> GetProduct()
    {
        string sql =
         @"SELECT ProductId, ProductName, Weight, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock,CategoryId,
             FROM [Product]

        return Db.ReadList(sql, Make);
    }

private static Func<IDataReader, Product> Make = reader =>
      new Product
      {
          ProductId = reader["ProductId"].AsId(),
          ProductName = reader["ProductName"].AsString(),
          Weight = reader["Weight"].AsString(),
          UnitPrice = reader["UnitPrice"].AsDouble(),
          UnitsInStock = reader["UnitsInStock"].AsInt(),
          Category.CategoryId=reader["CategoryId].AsInt()
      };
```

But when i write the below i get error.

```
Category.CategoryId=reader["CategoryId].AsInt()
```

How to get the CategoryId for the product in list?

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: It show error as 'Invalid initializer member declarator'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a nested property like that in an object initializer.

Instead, you need to set the property on the child object:

```
Category = {
    CategoryId = ...
}
```

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan: What don't you understand?

Comment: OK took few min to understand what did you meant when you wrote like. Will try and get back.

Answer (score 0):

The code would look like below.(If anybody else need help).

```
private static Func<IDataReader, Product> Make = reader =>
      new Product
      {
          ProductId = reader["ProductId"].AsId(),
          ProductName = reader["ProductName"].AsString(),
          Weight = reader["Weight"].AsString(),
          UnitPrice = reader["UnitPrice"].AsDouble(),
          UnitsInStock = reader["UnitsInStock"].AsInt(),
          Version = reader["Version"].AsBase64String(),
          Category =
          {
              CategoryId = reader["CategoryId"].AsId(),
              Name = reader["Name"].AsString()
          }

      };
```